# Show that $\pi=\frac{22}{7}-\frac{\pi}{4}\int_0^{\infty}\frac{e^{-2x\pi}\left( 1-e^{-\frac{x\pi}{2} } \right)^4}{\cosh\left(\frac{x\pi}{2}\right)}dx$

Tags: integration

An integral from maths world; pi formulas (50),

$$\pi=\frac{22}{7}-\int_0^1\frac{x^4(1-x)^4}{1+x^2}dx$$

We found another similar integral to it, via experimental with wolfram integrator,

$$\pi=\frac{22}{7}-\frac{\pi}{4}\int_0^{\infty}\frac{e^{-2x\pi}\left( 1-e^{-\frac{x\pi}{2} } \right)^4}{\cosh\left(\frac{x\pi}{2}\right)}dx$$

**Can anyone help us to prove it?**

Comment: Wouldn't be
$0=\frac{\pi}{4}\int_0^1\frac{e^{-2x\pi}\left( 1-e^{-\frac{x\pi}{2} } \right)^4}{\cosh\left(\frac{x\pi}{2}\right)}dx-\int_0^1\frac{x^4(1-x)^4}{1+x^2}dx$
the interesting part?

Comment: This is not true - set $u = \exp(-\pi x/2)$ to get that the second integral is strictly less than $22/7 - \pi$. The same substitution also tells you that you'll get equality if you integrate over the positive reals.

Comment: Correction on the limit on the second integrand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that $\displaystyle\cosh x=\frac{e^x+e^{-x}}{2}$. Let 
$\displaystyle t=e^{-\frac{x\pi}{2}}$, then $\displaystyle dt=-\frac{\pi}{2}e^{-\frac{x\pi}{2}}dx$. Also, we have $t=1$ as $x=0$, and $t\to0$ as $x\to\infty$. Therefore 
\begin{align}
\frac{\pi}{4}\int_0^\infty\frac{e^{-2x\pi}\left( 1-e^{-\frac{x\pi}{2} } \right)^4}{\cosh\left(\frac{x\pi}{2}\right)}dx
&=\frac{\pi}{4}\int_0^\infty\frac{e^{-2x\pi}\left( 1-e^{-\frac{x\pi}{2} } \right)^4}{\frac{e^{\frac{x\pi}{2}}+e^{-\frac{x\pi}{2}}}{2}}dx\\
&=\frac{\pi}{2}\int_0^\infty\frac{e^{-2x\pi}\left( 1-e^{-\frac{x\pi}{2} } \right)^4}{e^{\frac{x\pi}{2}}+e^{-\frac{x\pi}{2}}}\left(-\frac{2}{\pi}e^{\frac{x\pi}{2}}\right)\left(-\frac{\pi}{2}e^{-\frac{x\pi}{2}}dx\right)\\
&=-\int_0^\infty\frac{e^{-2x\pi}\left( 1-e^{-\frac{x\pi}{2} } \right)^4}{1+e^{-x\pi}}\left(-\frac{\pi}{2}e^{-\frac{x\pi}{2}}dx\right)\\
&=-\int_1^0\frac{t^4\left( 1-t\right)^4}{1+t^2}dt\\
&=\int_0^1\frac{t^4\left( 1-t\right)^4}{1+t^2}dt.
\end{align}

Comment: Well done @Solumilkyu, it was nice meeting you thank you.